# Is it possible to use jquery.tagcanvas.min.js plugin with same speed for rotation?

Tags: jquery, tagcanvas

hi i m new to jquery i m using this plugin jquery.tagcanvas.min.js for rotating images i need to know is ti possible to make it same speed all the time some time if u over on image it increases its speed  and changes it direction is it possible to make same direction and speed?
thanks in advance.
this code i use

```
if(!$('#myCanvas').tagcanvas({
          textColour: '#ff0000',
          outlineColour: 'transparent',
          reverse: true,
          depth: 0.8,
          maxSpeed: 0.04,
          minSpeed: 0.04,
          initial:  [0.04,0.04],
          zoom:1

        },'tags' )) {
          // something went wrong, hide the canvas container
          $('#myCanvasContainer').hide();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this link 
http://www.goat1000.com/jquery.tagcanvas.js?2.0

and change MouseMove and MouseOut function

Answer (score 0):

add option minSpeed: 0.8 or any desired value

Comment: It's not clear how this will help the OP; they already appear to have the option ypu specify in their code. Can you elaborate?